# Why is libtool's "current" used as "SOVERSION" on BSD, rather than "major"?

Tags: shared-libraries, freebsd, elf, bsd, libtool

On Unix-like systems dynamic shared libraries (.so files) have an `SONAME`.
It can be extracted for example with:
`readelf -a libfoo.so.0.3.2 | grep SONAME` -> `libfoo.so.0`.
The last part is also called the `SOVERSION`.
That version number marks versions of the library that are binary compatible (ABI).
So when a program links to one version of the library it can also use a later version if the `SOVERSION` doesn't change.

[Libtool](http://www.sourceware.org/autobook/autobook/autobook_91.html) has a `-version-info` mechanism to decide such a `SOVERSION` with `current`, `revision` and `age`.
The clue is: `current` is increased also on compatible changes and `major = current - age` is used on most systems to set the `SOVERSION`.

However, on BSD (FreeBSD, NetBSD, OpenBSD) the `SOVERSION` is set to `current`, which is mentioned in a couple of places like the 
[suse-wiki](http://en.opensuse.org/openSUSE%3aShared_library_packaging_policy#Versioning_schemes),
and I also tested this on the mentioned platforms.

**The question is: Why is libtool doing this on BSD?**
Why is this considered to be "the way BSD does this"?

That means every compatible change for Linux/Darwin/SunOS is an incompatible change for the BSDs, because the `SOVERSION` changes.

Comment: I traced libtool down to 2e68bf5aecc88e67b7b33e30802f05585a59e278 where this behavior is implemented in 1999 by Edouard G. Parmelan. Not even mentioned in the commit summary, though.

Comment: There is a bit more surrounding information in http://tickets.musicbrainz.org/browse/LIB-33. The most important links are in kepstin's answer though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to at least one developer who posted on the GNU mailing list, this could be considered a bug:

https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-libtool/2011-05/msg00007.html

That email is also full of useful references to the library versioning policies to various BSDs, which do appear to contradict libtool's behaviour

Comment: Seems to be similar with IRIX versioning: https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-libtool/2002-01/msg00003.html They added +1 for these because of some spec in some local folder and 2002 already don't know anymore why that would make any sense. version 0 is no problem, actually.